# Laravel 8 ZMQ Gateway Timeout

Tags: php, laravel-8, zeromq

I am using Laravel 8 and ZMQ. My zmq is working. If server side not working it gives me Gateway Timeout Error. I want to add if the server side not working it not givers error. refresh the page and send it close message or just refresh the page.
This is my ZMQ code block:

```
        $queue = new ZMQSocket(new ZMQContext(), ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
        $queue->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_LINGER, 0);
        $queue->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6116");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

            if ($i == (count($data) - 1)) {
                $queue->send($data[$i], ZMQ::MODE_NOBLOCK);
            } else {
                $queue->send($data[$i], ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
            }
        }

        $answer = $queue->recvMulti();

        return $answer;
```

I try `ZMQ::SOCKOPT_LINGER, 0`but it is not work.